# Word to describe things that have a tendency to melt?

Tags: single-word-requests

Things that can catch fire are called inflammable, similarly I want to know the word which describes things like wax or ice which melts as soon as temperature around them rises.

Thanks.

For example sentence let us agree that the word is 'meltable' but it does not satisfy my need.

***Example***- May be brotherhood is too 'meltable' to survive even couple of days under debris of burned buildings!!

Comment: You should really use "flammable" instead of "inflammable" since it's more clear.

Comment: Just about everything can melt, unless it sublimates, like "dry ice". Do you mean at room temperature?

Comment: *easily meltable*?

Comment: at not very high temprature may be like heating with a candle for a minute or so

Comment: Above comment re. "Easily meltable" could be tweaked to "tends to melt"

Comment: I tried to make *(low) melting point, mutable, immutable, viscosity, solidus, liquidus* and a few others as answers. In the end I had to VTC because you have no example sentence. Please read the SWR tag description.

Comment: @Mazura Yeah sorry, I didnt read the description of tag. May be now you can VTO. See edit

Answer (score 4):

***[Meltable](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/meltable):***

> - capable of melting.

The Free Dictionary

[image]

Comment: This doesn't include the 'readily' condition.

Answer (score 1):

**Thermally unstable solid**

Quoting from the book [Guidelines for safe handling of of powders and bulk solids](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=cp3zopuBur4C&pg=PA390&lpg=PA390&dq=Many+unstable+solids+start+to+decompose+as+a+result+of+a+small+heat+input#v=onepage&q=Many%20unstable%20solids%20start%20to%20decompose%20as%20a%20result%20of%20a%20small%20heat%20input&f=false)

> Many unstable solids start to decompose as a result of a small heat input, e.g., friction. ...

Answer (score 1):

***Deliquescent*** means "becoming liquid or having the tendency to become liquid" ([here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/deliquescent)). ***Liquescent*** means the same thing.

You could use both of these words to describe butter or  ice, but I am not sure about wax.

***Fusible*** means "capable of being fused or melted easily" ([here](http://www.google.com/search?q=define+fusible&sourceid=silk&ie=UTF-8)), but seems to be used largely for metals.

I also like @Josh61's suggestion of ***meltable***. Although this might not mean, according to dictionary entries, *easily* or *readily* meltable, I'm sure a lot of people use it to mean this.

Answer (score 0):

The technical term for *melt* is ***liquefy***, which can apply equally to solids turning liquid and gases turning liquid. (it is sometimes spelled ***liquify***)

The OED entry says:

> To reduce into a liquid condition. With obj. a solid substance; also
>   in Physics, air, gases. †Formerly, to dissolve (in a liquid).

An example of each use is quoted here:

> 1863   J. Tyndall Heat (1870) ii. §21. 26   Simply to liquefy a mass
>   of ice an enormous amount of heat is necessary.
>
> 1881   J. Lubbock Addr. Brit. Assoc. in Nature No. 618. 411   Oxygen
>   and nitrogen have been liquefied.

So something that easily melts is ***liquefiable***.

Comment: The leap from *can melt* to *easily melts* could use some explanation.

Comment: @choster I believe the Op may have edited his question. He is now talking about things which melt as soon as the temperature around them rises.

Answer (score 0):

The single word is, as Josh61 points out: *meltable*.

It's not easy IMO to run a single word through an [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=going%20to%20melt%2Cmeltable%2Ctendency%20to%20melt%2Cprobably%20melted%2Cwill%20have%20melted&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgoing%20to%20melt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmeltable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctendency%20to%20melt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprobably%20melted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwill%20have%20melted%3B%2Cc0) up against several other phrases and not have it completely blow the scale. From this I deduce that just like you, others are willing to word at great length in order to avoid using it.

[image]

In short, no single word for you. There is another phrase that knocks all of these out of the park though:

## **[easily melted](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=going%20to%20melt%2Cmeltable%2Ctendency%20to%20melt%2Cprobably%20melted%2Cwill%20have%20melted%2Ceasily%20melted&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgoing%20to%20melt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmeltable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctendency%20to%20melt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprobably%20melted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwill%20have%20melted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceasily%20melted%3B%2Cc0)**