# Is there a term for "meltable"?

Tags: synonyms, is-it-a-word, derivational-morphology

Full disclosure, I'm kind of dumb so bear with me. I've only googled a dozen or so thesauruses but I came up with nothing for things that are "meltable".

I mean, is *meltable* even a word? Has to be, right?

Comment: Mirriam-Webster has [meltable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/melt) as an adjective.

Comment: Since we all understand what it means (linguists would say that _meltable_ is "compositional", in that you can figure out the meaning  of the word from the parts composing it), it **IS** a word. How else could we understand it?

Comment: This question was already answered [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/309296/word-to-describe-things-that-have-a-tendency-to-melt).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is: the term for “meltable” is of course *meltable*.

As John Lawler observed in a comment:

> Since we all understand what it means (linguists would say that *meltable* is "compositional", in that you can figure out the meaning  of the word from the parts composing it), it **IS** a word. How else could we understand it?

It therefore **has** to be a word just as you suspected, and you have no need to consult some dictionary just to confirm your native suspicions here.

The same would be true of derived terms composed of productive affixes applied to it, like *unmeltable, remeltable, unmeltability, remeltability*, and so on and so forth.

Comment: But sometimes words have narrower or broader meanings. Is the default meaning here 'that melts readily at low/ish temperatures' or 'that will melt in a vacuum chamber furnace'?

Comment: Sublimable? Melting points vary widely, but not everything melts . . .